# "Connection timed out" error while connecting vscode to gcloud cloud shell

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I have set up the cloud shell for vscode as given in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/quickstart-remote-dev); however it stopped connecting to the remote shell and it was only connected once initially. No VS Code version change happened. Current VSCode version is 1.46.1
Following are the logs thrown -

```
[13:31:22.078] Log Level: 2
[13:31:22.086] remote-ssh@0.51.0
[13:31:22.086] win32 x64
[13:31:22.093] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+cloud-shell", attempt 1
[13:31:22.094] SSH Resolver called for host: cloud-shell
[13:31:22.094] Setting up SSH remote "cloud-shell"
[13:31:23.942] Using commit id "cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d" and quality "stable" for server
[13:31:23.945] Install and start server if needed
[13:31:23.951] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:31:23.957] Got error from ssh: spawn ssh ENOENT
[13:31:23.958] Checking ssh with "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[13:31:23.962] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe ENOENT
[13:31:23.962] Checking ssh with "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -V"
[13:31:28.385] > OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
[13:31:28.390] Running script with connection command: "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe" -T -D 50396 cloud-shell bash
[13:31:28.412] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[13:31:33.205] > 
[13:31:33.206] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[13:31:54.348] > ssh: connect to host 34.87.29.174 port 6000: Connection timed out
> 
[13:31:54.764] "install" terminal command done
[13:31:54.765] Install terminal quit with output: ssh: connect to host 34.87.29.174 port 6000: Connection timed out
[13:31:54.766] Received install output: ssh: connect to host 34.87.29.174 port 6000: Connection timed out
[13:31:54.768] Resolver error: The connection timed out
[13:31:54.781] ------
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to cloud shell directly using `gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh`?

Comment: I didn't try that..away from system right now. Will try and let you know.